# Does there exist a test for statistical significance to compare two distributions that is independent of sample size?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, nonparametric-statistics

Essentially, I am generating datasets in which **I can make the sample sizes as large as I want**. Therefore, any statistical test that I do between the generated sample distributions are somewhat meaningless because the statistics are dependent on sample size. In particular, as long as I make the sample sizes large enough, the test statistic can always be returned as "significant".

What I am looking to do, in essence, is compare two distributions of data, and not compare the means, but compare the distributions themselves, to quantify some measure of statistical significance. In particular, I would say that in my case, if such a significance test exists, you could argue that increasing the sample size would make the comparison, more accurate, but would ultimately converge to some **non-zero** significance value for sample size -> infinity.

The two-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test (wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test), is something very close to what I am looking to quantify, however, although this measures statistical significance between two continuous distributions, the test for significance is still dependent on sample sizes of the two distributions.

I am bringing this question here in hopes that someone with experience is aware of some kind of statistical significance test between two distributions that is **independent of sample size**. I am aware that in general having a large sample essentially translates to "we can now be more confident that the test statistic is significant!", but again I am looking for a significance test that directly compares two distributions where we may assume that the sample sizes are very large for both distributions, thus we have attained a distribution of the data that has converged, and thus we do not consider sample size to have an effect on the test statistic.

Comment: I think you should be looking at the effect size rather than the p-value in this case. Arbitrarily increasing the sample size shows that arbitrarily small differences can be quantified as "real", but that doesn't mean that arbitrarily small, statistically significant differences are meaningful for your application. With enough data, you might show some drug reduces risk of disease with p<1e-20, but if that reduction of risk is 0.0001%, it's pretty useless.

Comment: In general, no is the answer because statistical significance tests depend on the sample size. More context here would be useful. After all, if you have access to unlimited sample sizes then you don't really need statistics. Just keep increasing sample size and see what each of the two empirical distribution functions are converging to. Look at them and decide if they are different.